# Preventing an idle timeout with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-elb

The site I'm working on exposes a web service that sometimes accepts calls that take longer than 60 seconds to process.

Unfortunately the server sits behind an Amazon ELB that is configured with an Idle timeout of 60 seconds and since the ELB is shared across many clients of the hosting company, it cannot be configured specifically for our requirements.

The long running processes occur before headers have been sent so I can't periodically send white space to prevent the connection from being idle. I can't change, so I was wondering if it's possible to send some kind of header periodically which might work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PHP is not for long running processes at all. You can run php from the command line and you obviously won't get any timeouts.

Not sure what connection are you trying to prevent from closing.

Comment: It's a web service... Third party software needs to send large quantities of data to the service which is processed and a response needs to be returned with the results of the processing. Due to the way the third party software works this must all happen on the same request/response. There's simply no other way this integration can work within the constraints of that software.

Comment: Well, you're not going to make the connection last longer than 60 seconds if it's set to timeout in 60 seconds. Try splitting up the data or trying something else entirely.

Comment: Maybe I've understood it wrong but I thought an "idle timeout" as opposed to a regular timeout means that it only times out if no data is sent on the connection for a period of greater than 60 seconds. Therefore, if I can find away to send some information every 50 seconds or so then it should keep the connection open. Please tell me if I'm completely misreading this.

Comment: What data is being sent, how is it being sent? There's no such thing as 'idle timeout' in PHP. A connection closes when the request is complete. If the request is over 60 seconds (in your case), the connection is closed automatically.

Comment: The "idle timeout" isn't a PHP thing... it's something that's implemented on the ELB (see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-idle-timeout-control/). I'm not referring to max_execution_time or similar. The data I'm sending is an XML response that can only be constructed after the request data has been processed.